# Excel file reading with 2007 office connection string

Tags: excel, connection-string

Actually in my system having 2007 office then i am reading the 2003 .xls file with using the 2007 connection string

string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";

data is not reading. But if the first row first column data length is lessthen 255 then the following first columns data is cutting up to 255 character. If the First row first column is morethan the 255 character then the following first columns data is reading fine.

Is there any back word computability is there?

Answer (score 2):

I All

I solved this issue, by changing the connection string.

vasu